# Improving a poorly formatted slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, pause

I intend to highlight the differences between these two columns in the slide. It has ended up to be highly cluttered and although I use many `\pause` commands. The source code is included here :

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Overview(contd.)}
\pause
\begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Unsupervised Text Embedding
        \begin{itemize}
         \item CBOW (Mikolov et al. 2013)
         \item Skip-Gram (Mikolov et al. 2013)
         \item Paragraph Vector (Le et al. 2014) \pause
         \item Cons
         \begin{itemize}
         \item Fully unsupervised, not tuned for specific tasks
         \end{itemize}
         \item Pros
         \begin{itemize}
            \item Scalable, yet simple model
            \item Insensitive parameters
            \item Potential to leverage a large amount of unlabeled data, embeddings are general for different tasks
         \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        (Deep) Neural Networks
        \begin{itemize}
         \item Recurrent Neural Networks (Mikolov et al. 2010)
         \item Recursive Neural Networks (Socher et al. 2012)
         \item Convolutional Neural Network(Kim et al. 2014) \pause
         \item Pros :
         \begin{itemize}
            \item State-of-the-art performance on specific tasks
        \end{itemize}
        \item Cons :
         \begin{itemize}
            \item Computationally expensive
            \item Require a large number of labeled data, hard to leverage unlabeled data
            \item Very sensitive parameters, difficult to tune
            \item Potential to leverage a large amount of unlabeled data, embeddings are general for different tasks
         \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your theme, and regardless of whether or not use use `\pause` commands, here's a couple of options. Mostly, I've tried to divide content into coherent blocks, and move titling text to actual frame or section titles. But your given text is right on the edge of overflowing a slide, regardless of how many pauses you add.

Below I've got two different formats, either of which might be suitable, depending on theme and wording. But for a series of slides with the same type of content for various methods, I'd try to stick to one particular format, and adjust the wording of your text to fit.

Warsaw theme, including space for section headings at the top of the slide:

[image]

Default theme, with no space for section headings at the top of the slide:

[image]

Document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Warsaw has document divisions at top, will need editing on slide 2 unless very few divisions
%\usetheme{Warsaw} \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% Default theme has no document divisions showing, can keep navigation symbols if desired
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}
\section{Overview}
% Option 1: citations above, pros and cons in columns below
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Unsupervised Text Editing}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item CBOW (Mikolov et al. 2013)
    \item Skip-Gram (Mikolov et al. 2013)
    \item Paragraph Vector (Le et al. 2014)
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Pros}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Scalable, yet simple model
          \item Insensitive parameters
          \item Potential to leverage a large amount of unlabeled data, embeddings are general for different tasks
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Cons}
         \begin{itemize}
           \item Fully unsupervised, not tuned for specific tasks
         \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

% Option 2: citations, pros, cons stacked without columns
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{(Deep) Neural Networks}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Recurrent Neural Networks (Mikolov et al. 2010)
    \item Recursive Neural Networks (Socher et al. 2012)
    \item Convolutional Neural Network (Kim et al. 2014)
  \end{itemize}
%  \begin{columns}[t]
%    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Pros}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item State-of-the-art performance on specific tasks
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
%    \end{column}
%    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Cons}
         \begin{itemize}
            \item Computationally expensive
            \item Require a large number of labeled data, hard to leverage unlabeled data
            \item Very sensitive parameters, difficult to tune
            \item Potential to leverage a large amount of unlabeled data, embeddings are general for different tasks
         \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
%    \end{column}
%  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```